# struts2 iterator values into javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, struts2

Experts, I have a situation here. I have ArrayList of String[] (ArrayList of String arrays in Struts2 action class, I am iterating those values into javascript to pass those values as a two dimensional array to google graph by using

```
var twodarray = ["<s:iterator value='res' status='status'>[<s:property/>]<s:if test='#status.last==false'>,</s:if></s:iterator>"];
```

then passing that twodarray into google graph using

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(twodarray);
```

How google graph accepts the parameter is for example

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
     ['Month', 'Electronic', 'Electric'],
     ['2017/03',  400,      290],
     ['2017/04',  450,      275]
  ]);
```

When I use

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(twodarray);
```

Graph is not showing up, but when I display the value of twodarray or alert the twodarray, it gives me the exact data as two dimensional array like below.

```
var twodarray=[['Month', 'Electronic', 'Electric'],['2017/03',  400,      290],['2017/04',  450,      275]];
```

I am wondering how the variable twodarray interprets value to pass as an 2D array to javascript 
function. Is it passing as a string? I am trying to pass it as a 2D array.

Comment: twodarray = ["<s:iterator <-- might it be that you have the " coded into your variable, so you end up with an array of Strings instead of a 2D array in JavaScript? How did you check variable contents?

Comment: By javascript alert.

Comment: Good catch, Jan! I removed it, it works. I think I have to to get some coffee and come back.

Comment: You okay if I add that as answer?

Comment: Sure thing... that's the answer...

Comment: You might want to accept it then :-) Thanks and welcome to Stack Overflow :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable declaration

```
var twodarray = ["<s:iterator value='res' status='status'>[<s:property/>]<s:if test='#status.last==false'>,</s:if></s:iterator>"];
```

contains `"` that are not required by the iterator - so they probably end up in your javascript-variable making it an array of strings - or an array with one string more exactly.

Removing the `"` should to the trick:

```
var twodarray = [<s:iterator value='res' status='status'>[<s:property/>]<s:if test='#status.last==false'>,</s:if></s:iterator>];
```

Answer (score 1):

OK with Jan's solution.
A suggestion, I would create the JS array in this way:

```
var twodarray = [];
<s:iterator value='res' status='status'>
    twodarray.push([<s:property/>]);
</s:iterator>
```

It makes it more readable in your template and in the HTML (no burdening coma conditions and nested brackets)

```
var twodarray = [];
twodarray.push(['Month', 'Electronic', 'Electric']);
twodarray.push(['2017/03',  400,      290]);
twodarray.push(['2017/04',  450,      275]);
```